# Chrome 92 breaks button actions (Reset Password, custom VF) in SFDC - Known Issue workarounds

Tags: visualforce, chrome

2021-07-26, hundreds of orgs reported being affected by this [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-%5B%E2%80%A6%5Doss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX)

> Summary
> As of Chrome version 92, customers may experience issues when working across the Salesforce platform. This impact may appear with buttons that were previously functioning as expected, visualforce pages/components, or other content not performing as expected. In the Chrome developer console logs impacted users will see the following error:
>
> A different origin subframe tried to create a JavaScript dialog. This is no longer allowed and was blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576 for more details.

Are there any other workarounds besides those listed?

Comment: Similar error could be happening for aura components, where opening link in a new tab is getting blocked. Although not everyone could be facing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common reason for the non-functional buttons is the "Are you sure" javascript dialog that you might see encoded on a VF page `commandButton` like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Do Something"
                    onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false};"
/>
```

Not all of the workarounds suggested in the [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-%5B%E2%80%A6%5Doss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX) may be applicable/practical/possible to your org:

- Using Firefox or Safari
- Changing the way Chrome is launched

An additional workaround that I have discovered (besides removing the `confirm` JS function from custom buttons) is to run the application page in **SFDC Classic**.  This also addresses the Reset Password button issue which appears to use the JS confirm dialog mechanism

*Note: The **Classic** workaround does not "work" in **Service Console Classic**;*

Answer (score 0):

It has been observed that if you have a JS call before page postback are not working in Chrome 92, especially in cross domain scenario.

Try below workaround.

Chrome (icon)--> Properties --> Shortcut Tab -->Target Textbox.
You will see below setting in TargetTextbox
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

After that setting add below line. Restart Chrome and check.

--disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"

Javascript alert, confirmation box work with these settings.